# Incorrect value of Pi in Lua after 16th Decimal Place

Tags: luatex, strings, lua, luacode, directlua

The following is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\luaexec{tex.sprint(string.format('\%.20f', math.pi))}
\end{document}
```

It gives the output as

3.141592653589793`11600`

It can easily be seen that the value of `pi` goes on incorrect. Compare [here](http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/pi-digits?n_decimals_to_display=20&breakpoint=20).  The correct value up to 20 decimal places is

3.141592653589793`23846`

This has nothing to do with `luaTeX` or `luacode` because one gets same answer in `lua`. It has something to do how `lua` calculates value of `pi`. Is there a way to get correct value of `pi` in luaTeX or lua ?

Comment: See also [Truncation of Napier’s number (e) to an amount of decimal digits of my choice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522938/5001).The answers to that posting provide various approaches -- including (at least) two suitable for LuaLaTeX -- to calculating and displaying the contents `e` and `pi` to a near-arbitrary number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Lua manual, section 2.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1)

> Standard Lua uses 64-bit integers and double-precision (64-bit) floats, but you can also compile Lua so that it uses 32-bit integers and/or single-precision (32-bit) floats. The option with 32 bits for both integers and floats is particularly attractive for small machines and embedded systems.

With double precision, you can't expect more than 15 exact decimal digits, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell how to do it precisely in LaTeX?

Comment: @user61681 What do you mean? LaTeX has no float type. Exploiting `expl3` facilities you get double precision just like for Lua.

Comment: I mean this :  Can I get precise value of pi up to 20 decimal places  using lua in LaTeX document?  Yes or No. If yes, with what command?

Comment: @user61681, just hardcode the value you want for pi.  It doesn't need to be from a package because it's not a calculated value, and it's not something that might change in a future update.  Pi is pi, so just hardcode the 40-50 digits you want.  Also note that the level precision you are after is usually meaningless (only matters in a few rare cases).

Answer (score 12):

You can cheat and do this using Metapost via the `luamplib` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\mplibnumbersystem{decimal}
\begin{document}
This is $\pi$:
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef getpi =
numeric lasts, t, s, n, na, d, da;
lasts=0; s=t=3; n=1; na=0; d=0; da=24;
forever:
  exitif lasts=s;
  lasts := s;
  n := n+na; na := na+8;
  d := d+da; da := da+32; 
  t := t*n/d;
  s := s+t;
endfor
s
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    draw textext(decimal getpi);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

But I think it might be easier just to write the digits out by hand!